# ¿Cómo evitar sobreposiciones de contenido en etiquetas div?

Tags: html, css3, bootstrap-4

Tengo una tabla que muestra registros, ocupa la mitad de todo el monitor y la otra parte lo tiene ocupado un formulario pequeño. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Todo bien ahí, cuando intento redimensionar la ventana, el contenido del color rosado pasa a posicionarse debajo de la tabla pero a cierta escala.
El problema es cuando hago la ventana más pequeña, el contenido rosado se sobrepone en la tabla y eso no debería ocurrir [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código de la tabla y el formulario que tengo

```
<div class="row no-gutters">
            <div class="col-md-6 no-gutters">
                <div class="leftside">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <?php 
                            $mysqli = new mysqli('') or die (mysql_error($mysqli));
                            $result = $mysqli->query("") or die ($mysqli->error);
                        ?>
                        <table class="table table-hover" id="myTable">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Location</th>
                                    <th>Editar</th>
                                    <th>Eliminar</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <?php
                                while($row = $): ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $row['']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['']; ?></td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="index.php?edit=<?php echo $row['']; ?>" class="btn btn-outline-info">Edit</a>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="process.php?delete=<?php echo $row['']; ?>" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Delete</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php end;?>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-md-6 no-gutters">
                <div class="rightside">
                    <div class="col-sm-6" id="formulario">
                        <br>
                        <form action=".php" method="POST">
                            <input type="hidden" name="" value="<?php echo $;?>">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Name:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $; ?>" placeholder="Enter your name">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Location:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="location" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $; ?>" placeholder="Enter your location">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <?php
                                    if($ == t):
                                ?>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="update">Update</button>
                                <?php : ?>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="save">Save</button>
                                <?php end;?>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Y lo que he hecho en CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
            .leftside, .rightside{
                height: 80vh;
                width: 100%;
            }
            
            @media only screen and (max-width:800px){
                .leftside, .rightside{
                    height: 100vh;
                    width: 100%;
                }
            }
            
            .leftside{
                background: #e6fffe;
                box-sizing: content-box;
                width: 100%;
            }
            
            .rightside{
                background: #f3e3ff;
            }
            
            #formulario{
                float: none;
                margin: auto;
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;
                padding-top: 25px;
            }
        </style>
```

En propiedades del CSS es donde pienso que tengo el error y me gustaría saber cómo evitar esa sobreposición del formulario sobre la tabla al redimensionar la ventana.

Answer (score 1):

No entendi bien si lo que queres es que cuando sea responsive quede igual que cuando esta en desktop, en ese caso deberias ponerle un width:100% al contenedor general y width:50% al leftside y rightside. En caso de que no quieras que te sobreponga deberias ponerle un height al contenedor general: 100vh, y al leftside y rigthside un heigth de 50%.Creo que el error lo tenes en ponerle 80vh a leftside y rigthside, pensa que la pantalla completa ocupa 100vh, osea que en ese caso estas obligando a que se superponga,sino ponele 50vh de height a cada uno.

```
  <div class="contenedorGeneral>
      <div class="leftside"></div>
      <div class="rightside></div>
    </div>
.contenedorGeneral{heigth: 100vh
.leftside{height: 50%
.rigthside{height: 50%
```

Proba con eso capaz te sirve
Si lo que queres es que te quede el rosado por encima del azul, lo que deberias hacer cuando lo pones responsive es con la propiedad order acomodarlo. Es decir en responsive: contenedor rosa: order:1, y contenedor azul: order: 2.

Comment: Lo que no quiero es que todo el contenido en rosado se sobreponga sobre el contenido que está en azul cuando la ventana la hago más pequeña, por eso que aparece ese "1" que es parte de la paginación de la tabla por encima del botón "Save"

Comment: fijate que ahi lo edite, decime si te sirve acomodando los contenedores asi y cambiandole los height

Comment: Lo intenté pero todavía me muestra ese error, le añadí el `contenedorGeneral` al _div_ que tiene la clase de `row no-gutters` y le modifiqué los otros valores, pero todavía tengo ese error donde se sobrepone el contenido de _rightside_ en _leftside_